# How can I turn my simple dataframe into a publication-style table in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, datatables

I'm probably asking an easy to solve question, but I've tried for a few hours now with no luck. I've got a very simple data set as you'll see. When I just hit "data" and hit control+enter to run it, it presents the dataframe exactly how I want it to come out, but how do I turn that into a publication-style table in R?

The code is below for your convenience:

```
Conditions<- c("Control", "Antigen", "Adjuvant", "Antigen + Antagonist", "Adjuvant + Antagonist")
n<- c(5, 5, 6, 6, 6)
Antigen<- c(0, 50, 50 , 50 , 50)
Alum <- c(0, 0, 1, 0, 1)
CpG <- c(0, 0, 50, 0 , 50)
Antagonist <- c(0, 0, 0, 1, 1)
data = data.frame(Conditions, n, Antigen, Alum, CpG, Antagonist)
```

Please help!

Comment: What is the output format you want? Excel, text, PDF?

Comment: PDF would be excellent. Text would also probably work!

Answer (score 2):

the package `gt` will be helpful here. it has a lot of customization to create nicely formatted tables in r

```
library(gt)
gt::gt(data) |> 
    gt::as_latex()
```

or if you are knitting in a document in markdown (to pdf) all you need is:

```
library(gt)
gt::gt(data)
```